# How to correctly form Android HttpPost request - Server responds with ''406 Not Acceptable''

Tags: php, android, http, http-post

I have developed a small android application that communicates with server over the Http protocol, using json objects .

It was working all fine on my local machine, but when I decided (just in learning purposes) to upload my php script to some free hosting web service, I get the 406 ERROR.

I've done some research, and found that it must be that Content-type was not set in my HttpPost request. But setting Content-type didn't help.

This is the android code:

```
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> userData = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            userData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", userData_email));
            userData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", userData_pass));

            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(uri);

            // I tried this too
            // postRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(userData);

            ent.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

            postRequest.setEntity(ent);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(postRequest);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            Log.e("SERVER: ", result);

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result); 

            userData_fname = json.getString("fname");
            userData_lname = json.getString("lname");
            userData_age = json.getInt("age");
            userData_gender = json.getString("gender");
```

And this is the code from the server (really nothing fancy):

```
$mysql_host = 'xxxx';
$mysql_user = 'xxxx';
$mysql_pass = 'xxxx';
$mysql_db = 'xxxx';

if (isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["pass"])) {
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];

if(!mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) || !mysql_select_db($mysql_db)) {
    echo '-1';
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`='".$email."' AND `password`='".$pass."'";
if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){

    $firstname = mysql_result($query_run, 0, 'firstname');
    $lastname = mysql_result($query_run, 0, 'lastname');
    $age = mysql_result($query_run, 0, 'age');
    $gender = mysql_result($query_run, 0, 'gender');

    $return_data = array (
        'fname' => $firstname,
        'lname' => $lastname,
        'age' => $age,
        'gender' => $gender
    );

    echo json_encode($return_data);

} else {
    echo 'not found';
    exit();
   }
}
```

Now, it may be something with my php code (missing something maybe), but since I know only basics of php I'm asking you for help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You change:

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);`
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
```

To:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpclient.getParams(),
            timeOut);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpclient.getParams(), timeOut);`
```

Surely, it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna be sure about your php code you have to open that page from a browser and if you will see your data in JSON format then server is working fine! Otherwise your server doesn't retrieve `json_encode()` function.

Comment: Server is doing fine. When I post to it from a browser it does return json string.

Comment: Good. Maybe your problem is in Http connection. Have you put Internet Permission in manifest? It allows your app opening network sockets. Let me know.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: Hi Ted, if my tip was useful I would like you check my answer. I hope you have solved.

Comment: Hi, Emisilve86. Sorry for the late replay. I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` which I did not have, and now I get 406 error code...

Comment: `10-31 15:07:06.957: E/SERVER:(23705): The requested item could not be loaded!??&(Status Code: 406) 
10-31 15:07:31.431: E/SERVER:(23705): HTTP request was interrupted by the host!`

Comment: The request forwarded by the client has not been accepted, this is what happens when Error 406 is shown. The message "The requested item could not be loaded" could indicate that the item you are finding for eithr not exists or you haven't permission to load it. What kind of server are you using? Apache on linux? Try this e let me know: "chmod -R 777 <path-of-your-server>"